# Animations/Transitions not working on fancybox 3.3.5 and internet explorer (tested on ie 11)

Tags: jquery, fancybox-3

I'm testing Fancybox 3.3.5 to implement an image gallery and a form.

I've noticed that animations/transitions are not working on internet explorer (works well in chrome, edge and Firefox), I've tried several options with no success. I'm using the latest version of fancybox (3.3.5) and also the latest version of jquery (3.3.1), I'm always testing it on the webserver. I've noticed that with `data-type="iframe"` animations work (lack of some functionality for images), but not with images.

I've also tested with fancybox 3.0.47 and the animations/transitions work on all tested browsers including Internet Explorer 11.

I came across this codepen.io/davida26-io/pen/GmZVLZ and I verified that it works on internet explorer, that is why I found that fancyboox version 3.0.47 works well on all browsers.

You can check on the developers page http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/ that the images get no animations on internet explorer 11 but they work on other browsers. I cant find anywhere in that site stating that it does not work on IE 11.

I'm no expert on Java Script nor Fancybox.

With that said, if it works well with a previous version, is it possible to adapt the code from that version to the new one so that it works 100% in all browsers tested including Internet Explorer 11? How can it be done?

Comment: Well, works fine for me.

Comment: That issue has already been solved in the Github coments… here https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/issues/1950

Comment: Do you encounter this issue using the latest version?

Comment: Yes the issue still occurs on version 3.4.1.. I still have to comment /*overflow: visible;*/...

Comment: The problem is that 1) it works fine for me (Version: 11.165.171340; Update Versions: 11.0.75); 2) the proposed fix would break those cases where absolutely positioned html content is added (for example, small close button ar arrows)

Comment: I did some more digging into this problem and I found out that the problem is related to the zooming  of IE 11...

Tested it with versions 11.228.17134.0 build 11.0.80 and 11.165.17134.0 Build 11.0.75 of ie 11 and fancybox version 3.4.1, with overflow:visible; when ie 11 is 100% zoom the slide animations do not work, but if I put it with any other zoom (125%, 150%, 75%, 50%) t works just fine in ie 11...


Chrome, Firefox, Edge do not have this problem as stated before on the GitHub thread.

I hope this helps you figure this one out..

Thanks for your time

Comment: more info on this matter, I have an iframe that works well in ie 11 with 100% zoom and with overflow:visible; on 19'', 22'', 24'' monitors but does not work well on a 27'' monitor at 1440p, zooming it to a zoom other than 100% starts working well, so the problem must be related do sizing... ie 11 is not handling the sizing well...

Comment: Yes, thanks! That is indeed related to zoom level. I never realised that, because I always set display scale to 125%, IE11 then automatically sets page zoom level to 125% and then everything works fine by coincidence. But if I change zoom level to 100%, then animations break apart.

Comment: FYI, it turns out, that IE11 has issues with `backface-visibility: hidden`, removing these properties fixes transitions.

Comment: True, also confirmed on my side, hope it doesn´t break anything else :)